# How to edit responsive.less file in theme magento 2?

Tags: magento2, css, less, less-css

I setup `unero` theme which has `responsive.less` file in the dire 
 **web/css/responsive.less**. I need to edit this file.

first I took a copy of that file and past it to my theme dire which is **app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{theme}/web/css/responsive.less** and edited it, but no changes happend.

Then, I take it's content copy and past it into the file **app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{theme}/web/css/source/_extend.less** with my change, and also nothing changed.

Note: after each change I remove the pup folder content to clear cache.

so how to edit this file in the right way to perform the changes?

Comment: after changes, have you run deploy and upgrade command?

Comment: only deploy .. could upgrade make any difference?!